# How is EPD different / related to anodising?

Tags: materials, chemical-engineering, surface-preparation

What is the process of applying dye to anodized surfaces (specifically aluminum)?

Is electrophoretic deposition (EPD) just the process used to apply the dye to anodised surfaces?

Or is it a different type of coating?